# Bash: quoting a string inside an array

Tags: bash

In a Bash script I need to execute a command which takes the list of the existing databases from PostgreSQL:

```
getdblist_cmd=(sudo -u $backup_user $psql -p $pgsql_port -U $pgsql_user -d postgres -q -t -c 'SELECT datname from pg_database')

# Get databases list
msg
msg "================================================================="
msg "Getting databases list ..."
dblist=`"${getdblist_cmd[@]}"`
status=$?
if [ "$status" -ne "0" ]; then
    return $status
fi
```

This works but I need to exclude the `template0` database, but this does not work:

```
getdblist_cmd=(sudo -u $backup_user $psql -p $pgsql_port -U $pgsql_user -d postgres -q -t -c 'SELECT datname from pg_database WHERE datname != \'template0\')'

# Get databases list
msg
msg "================================================================="
msg "Getting databases list ..."
dblist=`"${getdblist_cmd[@]}"`
status=$?
if [ "$status" -ne "0" ]; then
    return $status
fi
```

It returns:

```
root@postgres /u/l/sbin# ./pgsql-backup-full-func.sh
./pgsql-backup-full-func.sh: line 145: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./pgsql-backup-full-func.sh: line 187: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I know that no escaping is possible for single quotes in Bash, so how I can manage this?

Comment: Did you forget the opening single quote `'` in your second copy of the script to stackoverflow? I feel like a single quote is missing before `SELECT`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using arrays when you should be using functions.

```
getdblist_cmd () {
  sudo -u "$backup_user" "$psql" -p "$pgsql_port" -U "$pgsql_user" -d postgres -q -t -c "SELECT datname from pg_database WHERE datname != 'template0'"
}

# Get databases list
msg
msg "================================================================="
msg "Getting databases list ..."
dblist=$(getdblist_cmd)
status=$?
if [ "$status" -ne "0" ]; then
    return $status
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a few options --

### Using double quotes

```sh
getdblist_cmd=(sudo -u $backup_user $psql -p $pgsql_port -U $pgsql_user -d postgres -q -t -c "SELECT datname from pg_database WHERE datname != 'template0'")
```

### Using one more variable

```sh
sql_query='SELECT datname from pg_database WHERE datname != '\''template0'\'
getdblist_cmd=(sudo -u $backup_user $psql -p $pgsql_port -U $pgsql_user -d postgres -q -t -c $sql_query)
```

Comment: Yes, you cannot put a single quote in a single quoted string